# Google forms - Linear scale

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

In google forms I have a section. In the section there is 4 questions. The feedback method is linear scale allowing the user to select between 0 and 10 for each question. The total score allowed for each section is 10. Thus if the first two questions were answered as 5 each then the remaining two must be 0. Of the scores of the four questions in the section does not equate to 10 then am error must ensue. Note the sum of the four questions cannot be below or above 10. Then an error must be shown.

Please help

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Welcome. In this site we expect that questions be specific, among other things. Please checkout [ask] for further details.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want to make a check among many answers (verify that the total sum of the answers does not exceed x value) and return an error to the user in case this is not accomplished. Sadly, this is not currently possible using Google Forms. You can:

1. **Use a [Form Submit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_forms_events) to make this check**. It will not be able to return an error to the user as this is currently not a supported feature, but it can decide whether to save the results or not, and possibly notify the user through an automated email in case they are not valid.
2. **[Create a WebApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) instead of a Form**. It can include Javascript code in the front-end that verifies your conditions, and displays the error if they are not met.